# Windows 10 modern/metro applications not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, modern-ui

So my metro applications stopped working, including start button and notifications button. When i try to open one it shows on second then it closes itself. I checked event viewer, and there were a lot of errors, they always appear when i try to open an application. Example when I press start button:

> Activation of the app Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy!App for the Windows.Launch contract failed with error: The app didn't start..

I know what might have caused this error, i done a stupid thing and i used a program Unlocker 1.9.2 and i unlocked Windows folder (That program is used when you want to unlock a file to delete it ) So i don't know what problems i made, is reinstalling windows only solution?

Comment: I assume you have attempted to restart your computer?  What folder did you used this program on specifically?

Comment: look in the eventlog and post the error messages that you see there

Comment: @Ramhound i restarted it few times and it still didn't work ( just turned it on and off , not that restart for deleting everything ), and i used that program on windows system folder (C:/windows/ ) and its all subfolders and files.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I already posted the error , here is picture (error when i press start button ) :  http://prntscr.com/99hhsq & http://prntscr.com/99hhzx

Comment: click on details and post a picture of the details.

Comment: Here: http://prntscr.com/99ke76 & http://prntscr.com/99kf09

Comment: the error code only means E_APPLICATION_ACTIVATION_EXEC_FAILURE - The app didn't start. Welcoem to the app crap world that was added in win8. sometiem creating a new user profile helps. and sometimes only a **refresh**: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/refresh-is-part-of-reset-in-windows-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it without refreshing windows, first i made myself owner of all folders and files in c:/windows I used command:

> `takeown /R /F *.*`

Then i gave full permissions to All APPLICATION PACKAGES in windows folder  used this command:

> `icacls "c:\windows" /q /c /t /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":F`

After I done that everything started to work fine.