# Windows 10 calculator exits on open

Tags: windows-10

So, after my touchpad didn't work after upgrading to the next build of windows (10586.17), I reverted to my previous build 10240. But now a bunch of apps instantly close when trying to open them:

- Calculator
- Alarms & Clock
- OneNote
- People

I've already done a bunch of research, but can't find anything on it.

Comment: I had same problem, try what i done maybe it will work for you: http://superuser.com/questions/1007854/windows-10-modern-metro-applications-not-working

Answer (score -1):

The most logical answer in your case is that since you updated your windows, it also happened to update all of your applications such as calculator, alarms, OneNote, People and Clock. Since you reverted your update, you did not revert the latest updates for these apps. Thus these apps try to reference values and variables that don't exist yet.

While I do not know how repair the situation directly, the best I can offer is to reinstall the apps to the particular version you want.

Comment: This does not really answer the author's question.  If the author reverted back to 10240, the new versions of the applications, were also uninstalled.

Comment: @Ramhound That is not necessarily true. An ideal example of this would be doing say a `yum install` or a `yum remove` of a package in linux. Just because you removed the package to revert to a previous version of it does not mean that all its dependencies would do the same as well. You have to explicitly state it to do this or modify the dependencies by hand in order to accomplish this. I know that the file systems memory does not change during updates or downgrades because what would be the point of a cleaned hard-drive every time you do so?

Comment: What does yum install have to do with Windows Store applications?  Do you know specifically, Windows 10 is able to roll back, to a previous version of Windows?  I have done extensive research on how the mechanic works.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not deny you have done the research. However because one operating system works like this, there is a high chance that others work similarly. Much like how `echo` and redirections can be found on nearly every OS to date. If my answer is wrong, do better and answer it yourself instead of down-voting the only answer so far.

Comment: I don't have enough information to answer this question.  Voting doesn't work like that.  If I find something unhelpful or helpful I vote.  If I can answer the question, I vote, and answer the question.

Comment: @Ramhound So if you do not have enough information so far, how do you know if my solution is not the correct one? It may not be useful to you but it can most certainly be useful to someone else and especially if someone is able to build on top of it.

Comment: Somebody shouldn't have to "build on top of your answer", the answer seems incomplete, you don't actually tell the user HOW to specifically solve the problem so these applications don't crash when they are launched.